# How To Use A Unique Constraint On Multiple Columns Instead Of Creating A Composite Key

Tags: grails, many-to-many, constraints, unique-constraint

The new system I'm starting has several domains that are just join tables for many-to-many relations. They are all like this example for Spring Security Core. In the case, of Spring Security, a "legacy" database is being mapped, so using a composit key is necessary.

My question is if it's possible to put a unique constraint on the combination of the fields instead of having to use a composite key and thus having to implement the get and other functions. I'd be quite happy to use the id as the key, but I do need to ensure the records are unique.

In other words, how could I add a unique constraint on secUser + secRole instead of creating a composite key in the following domain?

```
class SecUserSecRole implements Serializable {

    SecUser secUser
    SecRole secRole

    boolean equals(other) {
        if (!(other instanceof SecUserSecRole)) {
            return false
        }

        other.secUser?.id == secUser?.id &&
            other.secRole?.id == secRole?.id
    }

    int hashCode() {
        def builder = new HashCodeBuilder()
        if (secUser) builder.append(secUser.id)
        if (secRole) builder.append(secRole.id)
        builder.toHashCode()
    }

    static SecUserSecRole get(long secUserId, long secRoleId) {
        find 'from SecUserSecRole where secUser.id=:secUserId and secRole.id=:secRoleId',
            [secUserId: secUserId, secRoleId: secRoleId]
    }

    static SecUserSecRole create(SecUser secUser, SecRole secRole, boolean flush = false) {
        new SecUserSecRole(secUser: secUser, secRole: secRole).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
    }

    static boolean remove(SecUser secUser, SecRole secRole, boolean flush = false) {
        SecUserSecRole instance = SecUserSecRole.findBySecUserAndSecRole(secUser, secRole)
        if (!instance) {
            return false
        }

        instance.delete(flush: flush)
        true
    }

    static void removeAll(SecUser secUser) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SecUserSecRole WHERE secUser=:secUser', [secUser: secUser]
    }

    static void removeAll(SecRole secRole) {
        executeUpdate 'DELETE FROM SecUserSecRole WHERE secRole=:secRole', [secRole: secRole]
    }

    static mapping = {
        id composite: ['secRole', 'secUser']
        version false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that if you're allowed to add a new column that'll be the real primary key, e.g. an autoincrement or a sequence-based column. Then adding the unique constraint would be simple:

```
class SecUserSecRole {

   SecUser secUser
   SecRole secRole

   static constraints = {
      secUser(unique:'secRole')
   }
}
```

But I doubt that's an option :)

Note that Grails 2.0 has support for Hibernate Bags, which addresses the collection performance problems that this SecUserSecRole approach works around.

Comment: That should be secUser(unique:'secRole') or secUser(unique:['secRole']), right?